# In Rails, after using find with :select, my objects don't save

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Running something like:

@users = User.find(:first, :select => "name, lastname, salary")
for @user in @users do
  @user.salary = 100000
  @user.save
end

After this looking up in the Mysql table, the users aren't updated.

Answer (score 18):

ActiveRecord doesn't know the object's id, in order to save the data.
So include the id field in :select, like the example below:

@users = User.find(:first, :select => "id, name, lastname, salary")

Answer (score 2):

John Ruby is correct that you need to include the id of the object in the select.
Also, you rarely need to use the :select option.  You can with joins, or if there is a real performance issue with selecting the entire row, but this doesn't come up much.
And you really don't need to be setting all those variables to instance vars (@).  @user in the loop can be a local var.  If you do need all the users as @users you can do:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :select => "id, name, lastname, salary")
@users.each do |user|
  user.salary = 10000
  user.save
end
```

You might also want to look at ActiveRecord's update_all for simple changes.  But note this doesn't call any save callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using .update or .update_attributes instead: those are designed for edits (as opposed to .save, which is for creating new rows)

Answer (score 0):

Using .save! will also throw an error if it fails to save.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a pretty old question at this point, but the correct answer, I believe is that any objects returned by :select are read-only.

See the official Rails guide to Active Record querying, section 3.2:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Curiously, I don't see this documented in the API.